# Number of rotations to superpose

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Two lines A and B of same length both center at the origin in 3D space.

Suppose A and B are not the same.
What is the number of matrices that directly rotates A to B?

Comment: Why quartic equations ?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"  rotating $A$ to $B$? Can you give an example of a non-direct rotation?

Comment: You can *always* map $A$ to $B$ by reflecting across a plane, no ifs or buts.

Comment: Direct rotation: $R_{1}a = b$. More than one rotation: $R_{1}R_{2}a = b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of “direct rotation” that you’ve given in comments to the question, there is an infinite number of such rotations. You can rotate $A$ about any axis that lies in the angle bisector of $A$ and $B$ to bring it onto $B$. Taking $A\times B$ as the rotation axis will minimize the rotation angle.

Answer (score 1):

You can work out the problem using complex numbers. You are asking for the number of solutions of

$$b=ra$$ where $a,b,r$ have unit length.

This is a linear equation, that has a single solution

$$r=\frac ba.$$

If the lines are unoriented, there can be two mappings,

$$r=\pm\frac ba.$$

Comment: ok. i get this now. so this works for 2D? For 3D, I need quaternions? Sorry I didn't mention it is in 3D space.

Comment: nvm. just have to find the plane that contains the two lines.

Comment: no... it is not the same. 4 rotations can work if a plane contains A and B in 3D. Clockwise/counter clockwise 180 degree along axis 1 or 2. Since a plane can always contain any two intersecting line, the answer is always 4 unless A = B. There are always 4 real solutions for the quartic.

Comment: @rxu: maybe, but does that correspond to different matrices ?

Comment: There are two axis of rotations. For an X (two lines), the horizontal and vertical axes both can work.

Comment: @rxu: forget about angles, think in terms of matrices.

Comment: 4 unique solutions. Draw X on paper. Two axes of rotation on the paper with angle 180 degree. Since +180 and -180 degree gives the same matrix, this totally gives two unique rotation matrices. Third axis of rotation is perpendicular to paper with +theta and 180+theta angles. That gives two unique rotation matrices.

Answer (score 0):

4 unique rotation matrices in 3D if $A \ne B$

1. Find plane containing the two lines.
2. This plane contains two axes of rotations. Rotating 180 degree around one of these two axes transforms A to B. -180 degree gives the same rotation matrices. For an X (two lines) on paper, the rotation axes are the vertical and horizontal axes.
3. Third axis of rotation is perpendicular to the plane. Rotation $+\theta$ degree and $180 + \theta$ degree around this axis gives two rotation matrices.

Comment: meh. so i need to get the largest root from the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Actually, there’s an infinite number of “direct” rotations. For every axis in the angle bisector of the two lines, there’s a corresponding rotation that takes $A$ to $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are continuum many such rotations.  Let $a$ and $b$ be endpoints of $A$ and $B$, respectively, and let $S$ be the set of points that are equdistant from $a$ and $b$. It follows from the assumptions that $a\neq b$, so $S$ is the perpendicular bisector plane of the segment $ab$. Moreover, $S$ contains the origin. Let $L$ be a line contained in $S$ and passing through the origin. Now $L$ intersects the segments $A$ and $B$ at the same angle at the same point, so there is a rotation whose axis is $L$ and which maps $A$ to $B$. There are continuum many choices for $L$ and hence continuum many rotations.

Comment: Thanks that explains a bug I see when I am superimposing line segments.